# How to search for shared albums

Tags: search, google-photos, album

I have hundreds of Google Photos shared albums. How can I search for them?

I remember some words of the title, but it seems that the only option is to browse through hundreds and hundreds of albums to find it. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Google uses machine learning with the help of voluntary contributors to train it. Without knowing the content of your albums there is no much that we can do for you other than point you to  [Search by people, things & places in your photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128838?hl=en)

From the above link

> ## Search your photos
>
> 1. On your computer, go to photos.google.com/search.
> 2. In the box at the top, enter what you want to find, for example:
>
> - New York City
> - A name or nickname, if you've labeled people or pets.

Below the above-quoted section, there are more sections:

- Find photos of a person or pet & add a name,  with tips.
- Turn Face Groups off or on
- Advanced tips

  - Change or remove a label
  - Combine face groups
  - Remove a face group from the search page
  - Remove an item from a group
  - Change a feature photo
  - Learn about face models
  - Remove, add, or change people & pet labels to your photos

Related

- [How can I get a list of albums in Google Photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90614/88163)
- [A way to search Google Photos for photos not shared, or not in a specific album?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/97635/88163)
- [In google photos how can I get a list of all my album names and URLs that I can paste into google sheets or excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168273/88163)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. unfortunately it doesn't help. I agree google uses machine learning to find photos based on places, faces, etc... But it still uses regular searches for things like picture name, label, comments... And also album names. Also searches for people, places, things, etc... Do not search shared albums, only your own pictures!
Again the issue here is to find a shared album (or more) based on its title, not content. Just like you can search for album names.
After all it is just a matter of getting all shared album names in a buffer, then display those that match th

Comment: @DanielPalmans Answers should be used to answer the question, not to reply to another answer. Please read [answer], [What are comments?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and [What should I do when someone answer my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: If you are looking to make your feedback reach Google engineers responsible for improving Google Photos, the best you use their Feeback channel.  Click the help button then Send Feedback.